# Desc Order in SubQueries

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, sql-order-by

With this input, how do I use ORDER BY to get descending order for a subquery? It is not applying to the data in the column.

[image]

Comment: wrap the query inside another query and use orderby

Comment: @BellaPerez , pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Number of Sections in order by shouldn't be wrapped:

```
Select name,
(select count(*)
from teaches
where instructor.ID = teachers.ID) as 'NumberOfSections'
from instructor
where NumberOfSections >= 2 ORDER BY NumberOfSections DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by that you mistakenly quote NumberOfSections in ORDER BY clause.
You should use as an usual column name without quote.

```
Select name, 
    (select count(*)
    from teaches
    where instructor.ID = teaches.ID) 
    as 'NumberOfSections'
from instructor
where NumberOfSections >= 2 ORDER BY NumberOfSections DESC;
```

Comment: @BellaPerez , pls check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a correlated subquery, you can directly use Regular `INNER JOIN` among those tables including aliasing without quotes :

```
SELECT i.name, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfSections
  FROM instructor i
  JOIN teaches t
    ON i.ID = t.ID
 GROUP BY i.name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
 ORDER BY NumberOfSections DESC;
```

If you still want to use quotes, use double-quotes( `"NumberOfSections"`, in this case also possible to use spaces such as `"Number Of Sections"` ) rather than single for both places ( aliasing COUNT and within the ORDER BY list )